# SQL Management Studio Using Up C-drive space

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, hard-drive

I only have an 80gb hard drive, though just a few weeks ago I still had 20gb free. The last few weeks I've been running a lot of very large SQL Queries on a networked database through SQL Management studio and my hard drive has become full, completely full. I've done a lot of looking and the the only thing I could find was related to the actual database, not my client hard drive. I have not installed any updates or new software and have not done anything that would take up 20 gigs so I know it has to be something with the SQL Queries.

Does SQL Management Studio store query results in a cache somewhere?

Please help.

Comment: download *treesize free* and see what/where is taking up the space

Comment: An 80GB drive??? How old is that machine? If you are connecting to a remote sql server there is nothing from sql that will use any disc space locally.

Comment: I run a small c drive on one machine for various reasons.. the only thing that unexpectedly eats up to 50 gigs is pagefile and hibernate file.. as Alex K recommends you need to find out what files are actually causing the issue. http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Yeah it's pretty old. But it's my work machine which I guess they can't upgrade :/

Comment: database have a associated log file, you can detach it :P but make sure that u backup it goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Large queries that can't run in memory use [tempdb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms190768.aspx) which gets written to your HDD.  You can clear it by restarting the SQL Server or shrinking the TLogs.

Comment: The OP stated the database is "networked". I assume that means they are connection to a sql server and not running this locally.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for pointing that out.  Definitely is an odd case then.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking it has nothing to do with sql at all.